# How does System.Drawing.Image class work?

Tags: c#, image, graphics, picturebox, abstract

I was wondering why it is possible to set the Image property of a PictureBox, when the Image class is an abstract class, and therefore cannot be instantiated.

Does the Image.FromFile() method create a Bitmap (a derived class from Image) that it then uses to display in the PictureBox? If so then when creating an image from a file that is not a .bmp ,if for example i use:

```
Image.FromFile("test.png")
```

does it convert this .png file into a Bitmap in memory before displaying it?

I know how to do all of the above, and I know it works, but I am just trying to get my head around HOW it works when Image is abstract as I am not able to find much information on the matter - any explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By the way, from `Image.FromFile`: `Managed GDI+ has built-in encoders and decoders that support the following file types:
BMP
GIF
JPEG
PNG
TIFF`. Returning an instance of a derived class seems logical to me.

Comment: Yeah I am thinking too that it is returning one of the derived classes, however I was just looking for some solid clarification on whether this was the case or not - any references on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `Image.FromFile("test.png")` returns an Image does not mean that it returns an instance of the Image class. Because Image is abstract it can only return a subclass of Image.

The method `FromFile` determines what it returns based on what it finds in the file by calling [GdipGetImageType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also: The class Bitmap is not reserved for `.bmp` files. By using a decoder the FromFile method turns the bytes of a file into an in memory representation of the image. In general a big blob of bytes that specify the red, blue, green and alpha values of the pixels. That is stored in an instance of the Bitmap class.

An other type of file is a Metafile. These files do not contain pixel information but vector information. When a metafile is read it is NOT turned into pixel data in memory but the vector information is stored. This enables the Metafile to resize the image without loss of quality.

The method that is called by FromFile looks like this:

```
internal static Image CreateImageObject(IntPtr nativeImage)
{
  int type = -1;
  int imageType = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipGetImageType(new HandleRef((object) null, nativeImage), out type);
  if (imageType != 0)
    throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(imageType);
  switch (type)
  {
    case 1:
      return (Image) Bitmap.FromGDIplus(nativeImage);
    case 2:
      return (Image) Metafile.FromGDIplus(nativeImage);
    default:
      throw new ArgumentException(System.Drawing.SR.GetString("InvalidImage"));
  }
}
```

Based on the image type either a Metafile or a Bitmap obect is created and loaded. These two type derive from Image.

Comment: Just wanted to add that `Image.FromFile("test.png")` is an example of a ["factory method".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) which often return abstract base classes or interfaces to better hide the implementation details.